# How can I make a failing relay more reliable?

Tags: relay, electricity

I have a non-accessible relay that I believe is failing and working intermittently. It doesn't need to actuate more than once or twice a week. It is activated with 12v and switches 12v 15amps.

If I were to increase the activating voltage to say 15, would that make it work more reliably or would it just damage it? My thought process being a higher voltage would generate a stronger magnetic field and work more reliably.

The relay is potted in and cannot be replaced, I would have to replace the entire device which is $2k+.  I realize even if this would work it would eventually fail, but if I can squeeze more time out of this device I will.

Comment: Of the types failures possible with relays, I think failure to actually switch is in the minority. It's more likely the contacts are fouled up so the relay is switching but making insufficient electrical contact. What is the load?

Comment: Not much to go on here. Is the rest of the circuit wiring accessible? Perhaps an additional relay could be installed. What controls the relay?

Comment: Reducing the current through what are probably damaged contacts will help slow further degradation. Can you use the output to power an external relay that switches the load?

Answer (score 0):

Relays have a life span which is mostly determined by how much current and voltage the contacts are switching (and the inductance/capacitance and surge current) and how often they are called upon to switch. Increasing the coil voltage is unlikely to help if the contacts are worn out.

Below is a curve showing the life span of the contacts for a [common old-fashioned](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/307/ly_ds_e_4_8_csm54-1291204.pdf) plug-in relay. As you can see, 200,000** operations is a typical lifetime at full load of 15A resistive load, and that will be shortened considerably if there is much inductance in the load circuit. Motors, transformers and indandescent lamps are particularly bad because they have a surge current on closing and/or arc when opening.

** In Japanese (as in Chinese) the character for 10,000 (万) is more common than the character for 1,000 so \$10^4\$ shows up more often than one might expect.

[image]

I would be tempted to try to McGyver a replaceable relay into your potted unit but without more information we can't really comment on how feasible and safe that might be. Note that sealing relays up 100% is a bit of a mixed bag. Many power relays have ports that are intended to be opened after soldering and cleaning, to help reduce the amount of crap that builds up as the relay contacts open and close.

There are other things that can be done to increase the life span of a new relay such as making it open faster (and opening that port) or suppressing load surge voltage and current, but once it's worn out it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the failure is in the contact and not in the coil. At those currents contacts are likely to fuse together or get sticky and build up oxidation layers. Adding more current to the coil will probably not help actuate it if the contacts are bad.

[image]
Source: https://www.pickeringtest.com/en-us/kb/hardware-topics/relay-reliability/finding-relay-failures

> The relay is potted in and cannot be replaced, I would have to replace
>   the entire device which is $2k+. I realize even if this would work it
>   would eventually fail, but if I can squeeze more time out of this
>   device I will.

Potting hasn't stopped me from replacing or reverse engineering devices, it is possible to replace components with potting, it makes the job more difficult but it can be done.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for replacing it with the potting? I might try my hand at that. Couldn't hurt if I have to replace the unit anyway.

Comment: You may not need potting at all, unless it's getting hot I don't think there is an electrical reason for it (unless they need to keep humidity out). I would dig the relay out. On some pottings a bit of acetone helps soften the potting, but it can also ruin components so be very careful with the use of it if you use it at all. I have seen one case where potting was used on a very sensitive instrument to prevent mechanical vibration of components and to keep temperature even. Its unlikely that this is the case for your relay.

Comment: I believe the potting is for humidity/moisture. It is a power steering pump on a boat. My concern was getting it out of the potting, I'll have to give the acetone a shot thanks.